# Curl in PHP retrieve HTML into variable not working

Tags: php, curl

My code snippet (this comes after previous *Curl* commands to log-in and store cookies):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.example.com");   
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close ($curl);
print 'result: '.$result;
```

The displayed result just prints headers. In other words, the actual source HTML does not appear to be saved to the `$result` variable. I know the results are there because when I *view source* on the retrieved page - everything is there. If it makes a difference the page I'm requesting is XML.

Thank you

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do (since your code is working with example.com) is to provide either the exact site you're retrieving the XML data from, or find a comparable one somewhere that reproduces what you're seeing.

Comment: I can't provide the site as its behind a login. It's really a pretty simple XML structure. It looks like the $result variable is not getting the data as I tested with str_word_count($result) and it's retrieving 0.

Comment: Upon further testing, if I set curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE); and skip the variable it still returns nothing. It's as if the CURL command isn't working, but for some reason the data does show in 'view source.' The curl command also works fine from BASH so something else has to be going on here

Comment: Can you try your code on another XML source somewhere to see if it works? Then we can narrow it down to either your code or the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print 'result: '.$result;`

with

```
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

If you are looking to display the **`<tags>`**, you need to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

You've set this variable:

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

This is why you're getting headers.

You're printing the result to the browser and the browser sees XML tags and does XML stuff with them. The data is there because you see it when you View->Source. If you remove the headers your browser may complain about a missing stylesheet and display the raw XML. But as you've already proved to yourself, you have the data.

Comment: You're correct, I do have the data but I need to assign it to a variable for further parsing

Comment: I'm assuming you see "_result: [headers-n-stuff]_". If so, your data is there in the variable **$result**, which is what you're printing. You will need to do something else to process the XML, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: My goal is to extract the values from the XML, however I would assume that if the code is saved to the variable then by printing it, it should be visible. When I use curl for non-XML pages, the browser actually renders the HTML. I'd assume for XML it should at least allow me to display the raw data

Comment: This is going to depend on your browser and also likely your web server. Try something like `Header( "Content-type: text/xml" );` at the top of your PHP page so the browser knows that it's not text. Chrome will certainly complain if the XML isn't well-formed: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note_error.xml

Comment: This isn't entirely true either -- while setting CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 will remove headers from the output, you also need to set CURLOPT_VERBOSE to 0.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @rand'Chris's answer, you can **`remove`** both:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

and

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`

And you will no longer receive headers from `example.com`. Of course, since you're accessing a different site, this may not be the complete (or even correct) solution.